# Postman path parameter following = in the request url

Tags: postman

One of the requests for the tool I've been asked to update is the delete request which is structured as follows:

```
http://{{host_ip}}:{{port}}/lists/list_id=76218cb5fc45605cd632c26f5c5568ac/del
```

where the list ID will be different every time you send a request.

In order to simplify usage for end users, I want to be able to have them enter everything they need as parameters or headers in the postman GUI as they do for the other requests, rather than modifying the request URL, so I tried something like this:

```
http://{{host_ip}}:{{port}}/lists/list_id=:list_id/del
```

but if the `:` is preceded by an equals sign, the postman parameters tab no longer shows `list_id` as a path parameter.

Is there a way to make this work using a path parameter? Or is the best solution to explain to users that for the delete request, they need to paste the `list_id` obtained from the other requests into the request URL?

Comment: I don't think `http://{{host_ip}}:{{port}}/lists/list_id=76218cb5fc45605cd632c26f5c5568ac/del` is valid url. It should be something like `http://{{host_ip}}:{{port}}/lists/{{list_id}}/del`

Answer (score 2):

```
http://{{host_ip}}:{{port}}/lists/list_id={{list_id}}/del?list_id=1
```

Now users can pass the list id as query parameter.

In pre-request:

```
  pm.environment.set("list_id",pm.request.url.getQueryString("list_id").split("=")[1])
  pm.request.removeQueryParams("list_id")
```

this will update the list_id varaible and remove the query parameter and send the request in the format you want

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve what you are saying then there is no solution for your problem.

But I would suggest you change your URL. As Divyang said, your URL should be like `http://{{host_ip}}:{{port}}/lists/{{list_id}}/del` or `http://{{host_ip}}:{{port}}/lists/del?list_id=123` and then you can use params tab assign values to list_id.

But my best suggestion would be to use RESTful design: `http://{{host_ip}}:{{port}}/lists/123123` and make a DELETE request to that URL.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party so you probably already solved it. But if anyone else is looking for something similar here is what I did.
If you add just add ":id" in the URL, Postman adds a section called Path Variables underneath Query Params.
[image: Screenshot of postman]